# how python updates references to variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

For this while loop below. It is clear how the v1,v2,v3 are updated to new data objects based on the equation. But I do not understand how u1,u2,u3 retains the original values of v1,v2,v3.Can someone help clarify? So u1 points to the original data referenced by v1 but not the new reference for v1.

```
def findModInverse(a,m):
    if gcd(a,m) != 1:
        return None
    u1,u2,u3 = 1,0,a
    v1,v2,v3 = 0,1,m

    while v3 != 0:
        q = u3 // v3
        v1,v2,v3,u1,u2,u3 = (u1 - q * v1), (u2 - q * v2), (u3 - q * v3), v1, v2, v3
    return u1 % m

    mod = findModInverse(7,26)
```

Answer (score 3):

The *right hand side* of an assignment is evaluated *first*.

Then, if there are multiple targets, then the right-hand side should be a sequence and each element of that result is assigned from left-to-right to the targets.

This means that you first get a tuple with:

```
((u1 - q * v1), (u2 - q * v2), (u3 - q * v3), v1, v2, v3)
```

and then the results of that expression are assigned to the `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, `u1`, `u2`, `u3` targets from left to right.

So first, the current values of `v1`, `v2` and `v3` are stored, and these 3 names are only rebound to their new values after all the right-hand-side expressions have been evaluated.

Also see [How does swapping of members in the python tuples (a,b)=(b,a) work internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047524/how-does-swapping-of-members-in-the-python-tuples-a-b-b-a-work-internally)

Comment: Thanks - This explains it - "So first, the current values of v1, v2 and v3 are stored, and these 3 names are only rebound to their new values after all the right-hand-side expressions have been evaluated"

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)